# Can we have this sequence of transitive models of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

This comes in follow up of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474566/is-this-infinite-sequence-of-transitive-models-of-zfc-equiconsistent-with-conzf/4474586#4474586) posting.

Can we have a transitive model $M_\omega$
of $\sf ZFC$ in which there exists a sequence $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of transitive models of $\sf ZFC$ such that $M_m \in M_n$ for every naturals $m< n$, and such that each model (including $M_\omega$) satisfy all axioms of $\sf ZFC$  relativized to the lower models, but at the same time no model (including $M_\omega$) satisfy the lower models within it being models of $\sf ZFC$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

It is fairly straightforward to show that for any transitive model $M$ of (enough of) $ZFC$, for any $L, Z, W, S, \phi, T \in M$, the following sentences are all absolute for $T$:

1. $L$ is a first-order language.
2. $Z$ is the set of axioms of ZFC
3. $W$ is an $L$-structure
4. $S$ is the set of all sentences over $L$
5. $\phi \in S$
6. $W \models \phi$
7. $T = Th(W)$

In particular, then, we see that the statement “$M_0$ is an inner model of ZFC” is absolute for $M$.

So if $M_0$ actually is an inner model of ZFC and $M_0 \in M_1$, then $M_1 \models M_0 \models ZFC$, which contradicts your assumption.

Another way of phrasing it: fix some enumeration of the axioms of ZFC which is absolute for transitive models. Then if $M_1 \models M_0 \nvDash ZFC$, then $M_1 \models \ulcorner$ there is some $n \in \omega$ such that $M_0$ does not model the $n$th axiom of ZFC $\urcorner$. So there must actually be some such $n$, since $\omega$ is absolute for transitive models. This contradicts your assumption.

Comment: Oops, I missed that the question assumed $M_\omega$ to be transitive! **Really** not my day.

Comment: So, what you are saying is even a finite sequence is not possible, that is if $M_0,M_1$ are transtive models of $\sf ZFC$, then if $M_1$ satisfies all sentences of $\sf ZFC$ relativised to $M_0$, then $M_1 \models (M_0 \models \sf ZFC)$. Would the same hold if $M_1$ was a transitive model of $\sf ZC$ instead? I mean keep the rest of specifics.

Answer (score 0):

**Terminological quibble: *theories* prove things, structures *satisfy* (or "think" or similar, when using colloquial language) things. It's improper to say that a structure does or does not prove something.**

---

*This should be a comment, but it's too long:*

Mark Saving's answer is **absolutely correct**, and in fact merely requires the "outermost model" $M_\omega$ to be an $\omega$-model; full transitivity is not needed. However, it's also not quite the end of the story: it leaves open the question of behavior of *non*-$\omega$ models. In fact, it turns out that as soon as we allow $M_\omega=M$ to be a non-$\omega$-model, we are **required** to have a sequence of models of the type you describe, with each $M_i$ being transitive from the perspective of $M$.

For every (genuine) natural number $n$, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves "For every set $x$ there is a transitive model of the first $n$-many $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms containing $x$ as an element which is not a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$." This is a good exercise *(HINT: reflection)*.

Now suppose $M$ is a non-$\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. By overspill, the previous paragraph implies that there is some nonstandard natural $a\in M$ such that $M\models$ "Every set $x$ is an element of a transitive model of the first $a$-many axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$." This quickly gets us what we want: inside $M$ we can recursively define a sequence of transitive structures $\mathscr{M}=(M_i)_{i\in\mathsf{Ord}^M}$ where each $M_i$ is internally transitive, externally a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$,  and satisfies $i<j\implies M_i\in M_j$. *(For a limit stage $\lambda$, there is no "top model so far" but don't worry: just apply the overspilled result above to $\{M_i:i<\lambda\}$.)*

In particular, cutting off at "true $\omega$" (and letting $M_\omega=M$) we get the following positive answer to the non-$\omega$-models version of your question:

> If $M$ is a non-$\omega$-model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then there is a sequence $(M_i)_{i\in\omega^V}$ of models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with $M_i\in M_{i+1}\in M$ for all $i\in\omega$, $M\models$ "$M_i$ is transitive" for all $i\in\omega$, and $M\models M_i\not\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ for all $i$.

Put another way, Mark Saving's answer is optimal: the hypothesis of $\omega$-model-ness cannot be weakened at all.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, but here you proved my claim correct. If M is transitive, then it is an $\omega$-model. I think your argument applies if M is not transitive.

Comment: @Zuhair I don't understand what you mean. What claim of yours have I proved correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, you proved the sequence I wanted! But I think by saying M is not an $\omega$-model, then this means that M is not a transitive model of ZFC. Right?

Comment: @Zuhair Yes. As I said in the answer, Mark Saving addressed the question you actually asked; my answer is really just a footnote to his.

Comment: Good! thanks! Just to make sure. Its a nice answer!

Comment: @Zuhair I've cleaned it up a bit; I don't know why I was mucking around with the $c$-stuff, that was totally unnecessary.