# Is this theory with nested sequence of universes of ZFC, equi-consistent with ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

Based on answers to the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474947/can-we-have-this-sequence-of-transitive-models-of-zfc). Is the following theory consistent?

Add a primitive constant $V_i$ for each natural $i$, to the language of $\sf ZFC$.

Axiomatize $\sf ZFC^{V_i}$ for each natural $i$. This is the set of all $\sf ZFC$ axioms with all quantifiers bounded by $\in V_i$.

Axiomatize: $V_i$ is transitive; and  $V_i \in V_{i+1}$ for each natural $i$.

The point is to have this theory equi-consistent with $\sf ZFC$, since it can be statisfied by the non-$\omega$-model present in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4474962/489784).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Since "$V_n$" already means something, I'm using "$W_n$" instead for your new constant symbols.*

Yes, your theory (call it $T$) is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$.  As is usually the case for equiconsistency results involving complicated structural configurations, it's helpful to **think about the finite subtheories of the theory in question**. I'll give two proofs, one model-theoretic (and a bit overkill) and the other more easily translatable into a weaker metatheory (like $\mathsf{PA}$ or even $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$).

---

### Proof 1

Suppose $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, and fix a model $M$ of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. By the reflection theorem we can find an increasing sequence of $M$-ordinals $(\alpha_i)_{i\in\omega}$ (here $\omega$ is true $\omega$!) such that $(V_{\alpha_i})^M$ satisfies the first $i$-many axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Now consider an ultrapower of $M$, $$N=\prod_{i\in\omega}M/\mathcal{U},$$ by $\mathcal{U}$ a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$. Inside $N$, let $$\beta_n=[(\alpha_{i+n})_{i\in\omega}]_\mathcal{U}.$$ By Los' Theorem, inside $N$ we have

- each $\beta_n$ is an ordinal,
- $\beta_n<\beta_{n+1}$ and so $(V_{\beta_n})^N\in (V_{\beta_{n+1}})^N$, and
- each (true!) axiom of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is satisfied in $(V_{\beta_n})^N$.

Consequently, the expansion of $N$ gotten by interpreting $W_i$ as $(V_{\beta_i})^N$ is a model of the theory you describe.

---

### Proof 2

Here's a more proof-theoretic argument; the reflection theorem is still crucial, but we don't need to use ultrapowers.

For $i\in \omega$ (a *true* natural number!) let $S_i$ be the theory consisting of

- the first $i$-many axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$,
- the previous bulletpoint relativized to $W_n$ for each $n<i$, and
- the $(W_n)_{n<i}$ forms an $\in$-increasing chain of transitive sets.

It's a standard application of the reflection theorem that this is consistent if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is; in fact, for each $i\in\omega$ we have $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash$ "$S_i$ has a transitive model."

(HINT: fixing $i\in\omega$, using the reflection therem, show that there is a length-$i+1$ chain of levels of the $V$-hierarchy each of which satisfy the first $i$-many axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Now consider the "top model" of this chain.)

Since $T=\bigcup_{i\in\omega} S_i$ and (a fortiori) for each $i$ we have $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash \mathsf{Con}(S_i)$. Now suppose $T$ were inconsistent. Then there would be some $i$ such that $S_i$is inconsistent - $\mathsf{ZFC}$, being $\Sigma^0_1$-complete (provably in a very weak theory!), would prove $\neg\mathsf{Con}(S_i)$ and hence itself be inconsistent. So contrapositively we get $\mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow\mathsf{Con}(T)$. The converse implication is trivial, and so we're done.

Metatheory-wise, all we needed was to verify the reflection principle for, and the $\Sigma^0_1$-completeness of, $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Each of these can be appropriately done in $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$, so as usual we get an equiconsistency result proved over about as weak a base theory as we could hope for if we don't want to do actual work.

Comment: What meta-theory is being assumed?

Comment: @VioletFlame As usual, vastly less than $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is needed; even $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ is more than enough. Note in particular that **the following version of** the reflection principle is provable in $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$: "For each $i$, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that every set is an element of a transitive model of the first $i$-many axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$."

Comment: I've noticed that this theory though interpret $\sf ZFC$ yet it doesn't prove all axioms of $\sf ZFC$ over all sets of it, replacement can be violated, I think it proves axioms of $\sf ZC$. The question here can this theory have an $\omega$-model.

Comment: @Zuhair $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There are infinitely many inaccessible (or even *worldly*) cardinals" proves that this theory has a transitive (so a fortiori $\omega$-)model: just look at $V_\lambda$, with $\lambda$ the supremum of the first $\omega$-many inaccessible (or again, worldly) cardinals.

Comment: Yea! I know that. But I don't won't to go to large cardinals. You can add an axiom that forbids existence of inaccessibles. My point is that we can have a model of $\sf ZC$ and the $V_i$ would be models of $\sf ZFC$ within it, since the model may not satisfy replacement, then it might be possible to have an $\omega$-model of this theory (without going to large cardinals).

Comment: is the "top" model of this chain an $\omega$ model? I understand by top model, the union of all of them, right? This violates replacement of course. If it's  the union of all of these then it appears to me to be an $\omega$-model. If it is a model of the theoretic union, then its a model of $\sf ZFC$, I mean proved consistent by compactness, then it might contain non-standards, and from prior answer it must.

Comment: @Zuhair I think you're misreading the Proof 2 construction. For each $i$ we build $C_i$, a "long" (but finite) chain of transitive (so a fortiori $\omega$-)models of a "large" (but finite) fragment of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. The existence of $C_i$, for all $i$, implies the existence of a model of $T$ by compactness - but this model of $T$, unlike the models occurring in the $C_i$s, need not be an $\omega$-model.

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm saying. By "top" model you mean the model arrived by compactness, which is a model of T and it contains non-standards.

Comment: @Zuhair The only time I use the word "top" in my answer is in reference to the *finite* chains (note the "fixing $i$" bit at the start of the parenthetical), so I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: you said (top "model" of this chain). What does that mean exactly?

Comment: @Zuhair We're considering a finite chain of levels of the cumulative hierarchy $$V_{a_{i,1}}\in V_{a_{i,2}}\in...\in V_{a_{i,i+1}}.$$ The top model is just the last model in the chain, $V_{a_{i,i+1}}$. In general, as we vary $i$ the chains shouldn't be expected to "cohere" in any good way; in fact, it's not a bad idea to require $V_{a_{i,i+1}}\in V_{a_{i+1,1}}$ for all $i$ as well, just to avoid any anomalously nice behavior.

Comment: Ah I understand now you were refereing to the top model satisfying $S_i$ OK, then.

Comment: Can we build an $\omega$-model of $T$ just in $\sf ZFC$ without using inaccessibles.